# Searching a list to compare int and say true or false in SML

Tags: list, boolean, int, sml, fibonacci

Okay so the overall goal is to test whether or not a number you input is a fibonacci   number. For example `isfib(100) = false isfib(8) = true`

This is what I tried:

```
    fun fib a b
```

This finds all fibonacci numbers and puts them in a list.

```
    fun isfib(n) = 
    if n = fib 0 1 then true
    else false;
```

I want this to search the list for n and return `true` if its in there or `false` if its not.

Cant get it to work though it compiles but whenever I run isfib it gives me a data type error mismatch. This is driving me crazy please help!

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that the type signature of `isfib(n)` is expecting `int list` as input and returning a `boolean` as output when you intended an `int` as input. This is why it gives the error message about operators not agreeing. i.e. it is expecting an `int list` but received an `int`.

You can use `List.exists` to check that `n` exists in the `list` of fibonacci numbers generated from `fib 0 1`.

```
fun isfib(n) = List.exists (fn x => x = n) (fib 0 1);

isfib(8);
val it = true : bool
isfib(100);
val it = false : bool
```

Comment: Thank you so much I tried using the exists function at first but I just couldn't get the syntax right I was missing "fn x =>" in the bool statement thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to pay attention to type definitions of your functions.

```ml
val fib = fn : int -> int -> int list
val isfib = fn : int list -> bool
```

According to it, `isfib` expects a list of integers as the argument, however you are trying to pass an integer.

You need to be careful with types. ML is implicitly typed language, but assigning types explicitly can save you time.

Let's rewrite your program with explicitly defined types:

```ml
fun fib (a:int,  b:int) =
  if b + a + b < 40000000
  then (a + b) :: fib (b, (a + b))
  else [a + b];

fun isfib (n: int) =
  if n = fib (0, 1) then true
  else false;
```

If you try to build the program, compiler will point you to the expression which actually causes the problem: `n = fib (0,1)`. From function `fib` definition it can be seen that it returns `int list`. `n` is `int` in your case. So the problem here is that you are trying to compare integer with a list of integers. To eliminate this, you need to write a function which determines if item is in the list.

P.S. Also you can use `List.exists` function from the `List` structure, but I would suggest to write your own function first.